# Add animated jquery fade or slide effect to backgroundimage slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I would like to change this jQuery background image script so that the images will fade-in and fade-out smooth or by sliding one in or out.

Right now the new image just pops-in what doesn't look good.
Also can't figure out how to make the images load random.

```
(function ($) {
    var count = 0;
    var milliseconds = 4000;
    var transitionTime = 1500;
    var selector = "#target";

    setInterval(function () {
        var images = ["images/pic1.png", "images/pic2.jpg"];
        var tempImage = new Image();
        tempImage.src = images[count];

        $(tempImage).on("load", function () {
            $(selector).css("opacity", "0")
                    .animate({ opacity: 1 }, { duration: transitionTime });

            $(selector).css("background-image", "url(" + tempImage.src + ")");
        });

        if (count < images.length - 1) {
            count++;
        }
        else {
            count = 0;
        }
    }, milliseconds);
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you mean that you want one image fading out while next is fading in? It does look a lot smoother.

Here's a simple solution for that effect. Note that your images will have to be absolutely placed over each other.

You could make this a lot more succinct using the animation completion callback. If you used css transitions and toggleClass you could probably squeeze it into a few lines.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var milliseconds = 4000;
    var transitionTime = 1500;

    var $showing, $target1, $hidden, $target2;
    $showing = $target1 = $("#selector1");
    $hidden = $target2 = $("#selector2");

    var images = ["images/pic1.png", "images/pic2.png"];
    // You could also use this instead of incrementing count.
    // Just remember not to show the same image twice in a row
    var count = Math.floor( Math.random() * images.length );

    var showImage = function(index, duration) {
        var tempImage = new Image();
        tempImage.src = images[count];

        $(tempImage).on("load", function () {
            $hidden.css("opacity", "0")
                .animate({ opacity: 1 }, { duration: duration })
                .css("background-image", "url(" + tempImage.src + ")");

            $showing.animate({ opacity: 0 }, { duration: duration });

            var $temp = $showing;
            $showing = $hidden;
            $hidden = $temp;
        });
    };

    // show the first image immediately
    showImage(count, 0);

    setInterval(function () {
        showImage(count, transitionTime);

        if (count < images.length - 1) {
            count++;
        }
        else {
            count = 0;
        }
    }, milliseconds);
});
```

Comment: Dear robvdv thank you for your help, I cant get it to work. I don't understand the selector1 and selector2. I want to target a single div. Could you maybe push it in a JSFiddle so I understand :D

Comment: The example works perfect only I don't know how to use it. Using wordpress I would like to target a backgroundimage of a div. changing background image with the var images in the jQuery. Then making a nice transition from one to the other images just like your example.

Comment: [edit] Ah, okay. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/robvdv/6npy057j/2/

You should be able to point it at an arbitrary div and have it do what you want. There may be wrinkles.